# sed - how to print regex match on particular lines

Tags: shell, sed

I want to print a match only of particular lines with  sed;
`sed '1,4 /regextomatch/p'`:

sed: -e expression #1, char 5: unknown command: `/'

What is a command for print?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest:

```
sed -n '1,4{/regextomatch/p}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use quit command:

```
sed -n '/regex/p;4q' file
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather do this:

```
head -n 4 filename | grep regextomatch
```